# Can't deploy project to firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-console, firebase-tools

I try to deploy my app to firebase but it's fail.

> $ firebase deploy --project af2test
>
> ⚠  Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of
> new features. ⚠  Please run firebase login --reauth
>
> Error: Unable to authorize access to project af2test
>
> Note: This version of the Firebase CLI is only compatible with
> projects upgraded to the new Firebase Console. To access firebase.com
> apps, you will need to use a previous version: npm install -g
> firebase-tools@^2.1
>
> To access the Firebase Console, visit
> https://console.firebase.google.com/
>
> Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help

Look like firebase-tools think that I have old version firebase app. But, I'm just create new project in a new console and it still not working. It used to work yesterday. I use latest firebase-tools from npm

> $ firebase -V
>
> 3.6.0

If i downgrade to 2.1. It will ask me to upgrade?Any ideas to fix this?

> $ firebase deploy --project af2test
>
> Error: CLI is out of date (on
> 2.2.1 , need at least 3.0.0)
>
> Run npm install -g firebase-tools to upgrade.

Comment: What it's saying is that it can't access project af2test. Check to see if that project shows up when you run firebase list. Look for project id, not instance name.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Many Thanks, it must be project id not a project name. It's my fault

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MichaelBleigh had the answer

run

```
firebase list
```

which shows something like:

```
┌─────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name    │ Project ID / Instance │ Permissions │
├─────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ af2test │ af2test-f289d         │ Owner       │
└─────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Use the project id to deploy with

```
firebase deploy --project af2test-f289d
```

Comment: this seems to have been changed to `firebase projects:list`

Comment: yes. correct. firebase projects:list works fine.