# Firebase Deploy - "Unable to Authorize" error

Tags: javascript, firebase, cmd, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I tried to deploy a very simple site for a Firebase project I have set up, and followed the following steps:

1. firebase login (I was already logged in since I have other projects I'm working on)
2. firebase init (created the **.firebaserc** and **database.rules.json** files).
3. firebase deploy

On deploy, I keep getting the following error message:

> λ firebase deploy
>
> !  Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of
>   new features.
>
> !  Please run firebase login --reauth
>
> Error: Unable to authorize access to project [PROJECT NAME]

I succesfully ran **firebase login --reauth** and I still get this.

Anyone know what I could be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43251225/cant-deploy-project-to-firebase)

It seems that when deploying, you're supposed to deploy with:

```
firebase deploy --project [PROJECT ID, not PROJECT NAME]
```

Answer (score 7):

First warning shows you have to update firebase-cli.

Run this command to update:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Your project may not have been linked which causes that error.

Run this command to link the project:

```
firebase use --add
```

It will list down the projects in your firebase account, select the correct one and try deploying the project using:

```
firebase deploy
```

PS: You don't have to append project_id to `deploy` command every time once you run `use --add` command