# Cross-project access to Firebase Database from a service account

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

I have a Firebase project that does not have billing enabled. I want to create database backups using a VM that belongs to another, billing-enabled project. The backup script is as simple as:

```
.npm/bin/firebase --project $PROJECT_ID database:get /
```

A freshly created Service Account is assigned to the VM running this script (through GCE). If this account doesn't have access to project `$PROJECT_ID`, then obviously this fails:

```
Error: Authorization failed. This account is missing the following required permissions on project $PROJECT_ID:

firebase.projects.get
firebasedatabase.instances.get
```

But giving these specific permissions to the service account, or even assigning "Owner" role to that project doesn't make it much better. Instead:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 404, The specified project was not found.
```

Running with `--debug` shows that specifically `GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT_ID` returns 404.

The project exists, which I verify by running the exact same command with my own (non-service) account on my workstation. I have also verified that the account is the correct one by running `gcloud auth list` on the VM. The project also shows up in the `gcloud projects list` output on the same VM.

Is there a way to make the service account work cross-project and access Firebase Database?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Run Below Command in your cli: **firebase use --add**

I saw this solution at : https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/?authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue,

Someone else created the firebase app for my team, I had owner permissions.

This worked for me, try the command:  `firebase use --add`

Props to  Paco Zevallos for a comment that led me to the solution.

I saw this solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263918/5283424

Check that solution for additional commands and troubleshooting.